# Groovy: best way to perform long running jobs in parallel

Tags: groovy, concurrency

I go through the GPars library in Groovy and try to figure out how to achieve below targets:

1. Run a number of jobs as closure in parallel;
2. Support timeout in each job or as a whole;
3. Support cancellation;
4. The job itself may fork other long running job with timeout as well.

It looks like there are several ways: dataflow, asynchronous invocation, fork/join... But what is the best way to do so with regards to reliability and flexibility?